# Efficient way to search for a node with a specific attribute in a tree and assign the attributes of the tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, tree-traversal

I have a tree. For example the following one:
root

```
      a
    /   \
   b     c
  / \   / \
 e   d f   g
```

Every node in the tree has an attribute `attr1`. If a node's `attr1` has a value of 1. Then the `attr2` (another attribute) of all nodes on the path to this node, should make to 1. But we don't know if any of the nodes has a the value 1 in its `attr1`.
The idea I have to solve the problem is, to traverse through the tree (pre-order). While traversing I will have a `FIFO` container (`queue`) and every time I go downwards I will add to the queue and when going upwards I will remove the nodes which are bellow. So I have always the path to the current node. If then the node has `attr1 == 1`, then I must iterate the path again and set the `attr2` of all nodes in the path to 2.
But I don't know if there is a more efficient way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def update(node):
    if node is None:
        return False
    upd_left = update(node.left)
    upd_right = update(node.right)

    node.attr2 = 1 if upd_left or upd_right or node.attr1 == 1 else node.attr2
    return node.attr2 == 1
```

I think this will do what you expect as we are not iterating over the queue again and again.
The worst case complexity of your approach in case of a skewed tree will be `O`(n<sup>2</sup>). As for each node, you have to traverse the queue, if `attr1==1` for each node.

But, in the above code, the complexity will be atmost `O(n)`. Because you are visiting each node only once.

Comment: God damned. That looks great and I think it should work. Has this algorithm a specific name?

Comment: DFS, that's it :)

Comment: It is somehow DFS, because it goes deep first. But the magic are the last two lines in your code. Anyway very nice